# SignalType.CANCEL ignores publishOn operator

Tags: java, project-reactor

I wonder why cancel signal is handled in a different way than the others.
Anybody knows whether this is intentional?

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.elastic();

Disposable disposable =
   Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
       .publishOn(scheduler)
       .doFinally(signalType -> {
           if (signalType == SignalType.CANCEL) {
               // caller thread  - why ??
           } else {
              // elastic thread
           }
       }).log()
      .subscribe();
```

For example

```
Mono.just(1)
    .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
    .doFinally(signalType -> {
        disposable.dispose();
     })
    .subscribe();
```

produces output:

```
14:37:36.308 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxDoFinally.DoFinallyFuseableSubscriber)
14:37:36.308 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | request(unbounded)
14:37:37.324 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onNext(0)
14:37:38.324 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onNext(1)
14:37:39.325 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onNext(2)
14:37:39.387 [parallel-2] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | cancel()
```

And

```
Thread.sleep(4000);
disposable.dispose();
```

produces output:

```
14:39:22.380 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxDoFinally.DoFinallyFuseableSubscriber)
14:39:22.380 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | request(unbounded)
14:39:23.412 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onNext(0)
14:39:24.412 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onNext(1)
14:39:25.414 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onNext(2)
14:39:26.400 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | onNext(3)
14:39:26.400 [main] INFO reactor.Flux.DoFinallyFuseable.1 - | cancel()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `publishOn` operator will only be invoked when a signal is emitted from the source and travels downstream.

The cancel request, however, is forwarded upstream and then the handlers are executed. A cancel signal is not emitted by the source.